# Windows 7 boot failure on a Lenovo Thinkpad Z61m 9450HAG

Tags: windows-7, boot, thinkpad

I recently did a full upgrade of Windows 7 on my Thinkpad. Everything worked fine after up until the second reboot (the first reboot after some updates installed worked OK).

At second reboot time the system would just black screen before the Windows logo appears. Disk/wireless/power/battery lights are all lit and the disk light is active (flickering).

However, if I remove my battery and boot with just power it boots fine and quickly, and everything is OK.

Any help on why this won't boot with battery plugged in is greatly appreciated. I need to take this battery out on the road/trains, etc.

A little more detail on this story.

The battery I had inserted when doing the (failed) boot was a long life battery.  I have not tried inserting this battery when Windows is logged in.

I have another (normal life) battery that I have charged up within Windows. It has just got to 100% and I am about to reboot with it in. I am using the Lenovo power manager to diagnose the battery - all seems OK.

I will report back shortly as to the outcome.

---

OK, so I chose the reboot option from within Windows, the machine seemed to shutdown okay, but then stalled. It didn't turn off completely and didn't reboot, but just sat, with the fan humming, somewhere in between!

I had to hold the power button in for a few seconds until the fan stopped and then hit the power button again to boot the machine from fresh.

One good thing, with this battery (the normal one) it booted into Windows 7 the first time with a battery!

So, now I have rebooting issues.

I have 3 errors in the event log:

1. A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the lxdxCATSCustConnectService service to connect.
2. The lxdxCATSCustConnectService service failed to start due to the following error:

   > The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
3. The following boot-start or system-start driver(s) failed to load: 
   cdrom

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There have been some issues with batteries and Windows 7 reported.  If the battery is poor the system shuts down. Microsoft says no issue but many report batteries do not last after upgrade.  Wondering if Windows 7 thinks battery is too low?

What happemns if the battery is put back in after a sucessful boot?  Anything in the event log?